# Combing multiple Arrays using concat() method

Tags: javascript

```
function joinArrayOfArrays(arr) {
  var startingArray = arr[0];
  var newArray = [];

 for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   newArray = startingArray.concat(arr[i]);
  
 }

  return newArray;
}

var output = joinArrayOfArrays([[1, 4], [true, false], ['x', 'y']]);
console.log(output); // --> [1, 4, true, false, 'x'
```

I want to loop through a for loop and using the concat() method and compile the results in single array. I cannot figure it out Any help?

Comment: you've just got your variables mixed up. `newArray = startingArray.concat(arr[i])` should be `newArray = newArray.concat(arr[i])` (And you of course don't need `startingArray` at all, it's handled in the first iteration of the loop.)

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+flatten+array) of [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10865025/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon: But this question is trying to make the function, not figure out what function to use.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj There are 83 answers on this question; some of them also use `for` loops.

Comment: @SebastianSimon: Oh, I understand.  Going to flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

you can do it that way using `array#flat`

```
[[1, 4], [true, false], ['x', 'y']].flat()

//(6) [1, 4, true, false, "x", "y"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Option one is to destructure your array into `concat`, since concat can accept multiple arguments:

```js
function joinArrayOfArrays(arr) {
  return [].concat(...arr);
}
```

Option two would be to [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) your array:

```js
function joinArrayOfArrays(arr) {
  return arr.flat();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reassigning `newArray` each time so that won't work.  Just remove `startingArray` completely and it will work:

```js
function joinArrayOfArrays(arr) {
  var newArray = [];

 for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   newArray = newArray.concat(arr[i]);
  
 }

  return newArray;
}

var output = joinArrayOfArrays([[1, 4], [true, false], ['x', 'y']]);
```

Of course, you could use [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) like mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66629401/14469685), or also `[].concat(...arr)` from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66629419/14469685) too.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the code as little as possible a solution that works well is:

```
function joinArrayOfArrays(arr) {
  var newArray = [];

 for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   console.log(arr[i])
   newArray = newArray.concat(arr[i]);
  
 }

  return newArray;
}

var output = joinArrayOfArrays([[1, 4], [true, false], ['x', 'y']]);
console.log(output);//->[1, 4, true, false, "x", "y"]
```

Effectively another way is to use `arr.flat()`;